# Android: Using my own customized layout to fill a scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, custom-component

I've been learning and building an Android application from scratch and I've hit a wall.
I read on the android developer page about customizable UI components and figured I could use those to contain messages for a chat page in my application.

I have made the XML files but I have no idea how to call those layout files from my code.
At the moment I read my messages from an array and then go through a loop making a TextView and setting the necessary properties for it through code, then adding it to a RelativeLayout within a scrollView. This all works fine but I want my messages to display more information (such as time and if the recipient has received/read it), this is where the new XML files come in, they have the field and layout already set up, so I figured I could just call those, set some variables and be done with it.

As I've stated before, the problem is that I have no idea how to reference the layout files inside my code. I've already read all the articles on the android developer page concerning building your own UI elements and I've also googled my fair share, but apparently I'm either the only one who has thought of doing it this way, or I can't find the right keywords for it. So now I'm asking you guys. Thanks ahead for any answers you guys can give me.

**Edit:**
I've been doing some research, and I think what I need to do is write my own adapter to work with my own class of messages and my own XML layout for those messages. However I have no idea where to begin with this, since I can't find any good documentation on how to write your own adapters.

Comment: I need to clarify. I think the following is basically what you're trying to do: In your ScrollView add newMessage to the relativeLayout, then add timeAndDateLayout.xml below newMessage, then be able to add newMessage2 below timeAndDateLayout.xml, then again add timeAndDateLayout.xml(with different values) below newMessage2

Is that basically what you're wanting?

Comment: Sort of, yes. I have created an XML file which has 2 TextViews in it, one for time/date and one for the message. When I get a new message (or when loading them) I want to be able to add them to my scrollview using the XML file.

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer, then accept it, since my answer really wasn't the solution, and it would make it more noticeable for those whom need the info. That is, if you care enough to bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in how I did it (and if you are running in to the same problem yourself):
For every list I wanted to create with my own random set of data I created my own adapter which extends BaseAdapter. By simply overriding the getView method it's possible to inflate and fill the different parts of your listitems.
I used [this](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/vladimir_vivien/2011/09/creating_android_view_adapters_is_easy_but_beware_) tutorial to help me with creating my own adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, but that will create a new TextView ignoring whatever layout you had:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(message);
scrollView.addView(textView);
textView.setText(timeAndDate);
scrollView.addView(textView);
```

I've never personally used ScrollView, so I'm not 100% sure on the above functionality, but it matches my experience with LinearLayout and RelativeLayout.

Alternatively, since you have your customr layout already, you would do:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(messageTimeDate);
scrollView.addView(textView);
```

That's essentially how you could handle it. I'm not 100% sure if you could add textView more than once in either implementation. If that throws an exception, you could use an array list of text views, such as:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
ArrayList<TextView> textView = new ArrayList<TextView>();
textView.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView));
textView.get(index).setText(messageTimeDate);
scrollView.addView(textView.get(index).getId());
```

Wherever I put textView for the id, you could use message or timeDate, and make two of each thing I referenced, then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not really what I was looking for.
I have found another how to do it though, I'm now using an Adapter and assigning a ViewBinder to it to specify what data goes in which fields.
Thanks for the help though.

Comment: No problem. I've never used ViewBind or Adapter, but I'm sure that would be an easier approach. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: For those interested in how I did it (and if you are running in to the same problem yourself): For every list I wanted to create with my own random set of data I created my own adapter which extends BaseAdapter. By simply overriding the getView method it's possible to inflate and fill the different parts of your listitems.
I used [this](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/vladimir_vivien/2011/09/creating_android_view_adapters_is_easy_but_beware_) tutorial to help me with creating my own adapters